Complex SEM Model in lavaan with moderations of latent variables
wished SEM Model
I need to model the image in R, and I'm a beginner. I tried to do it as follows, but I'm not sure if it's correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
We have longitudinal data!
measurement point 1: A, X, Y, C
mesurement point 2: Z, U, B, R, D
mesurement point 3: W

`model <- '
  # measurement model
  A =~ A1 + A2
  Y =~ Y1 + Y2 
  X =~ X1 + X2
  R =~ R1 + R2
  U =~ U1+ U2
  Z =~ Z1 + Z2
  B =~ B1+ B2
  W =~ W1 + W2
  # regressions
  X ~ A * C
  U ~ Y * X
  Z ~ Y * X
  R ~ B * D
  # Regression model including interactions
  W ~ U * Z + U * R
  W ~ Y * X
  # covariances (not in picture)
  A ~~ B
  A ~~ W
  B ~~ W
  X ~~ R
  C ~~ D
  U ~~ Z
       '
fit.mod <- sem(model2, data = SEM_wide, estimator="MLR",std.lv = TRUE, std.ov = TRUE)

summary(fit.mod, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)`


You are trying to use the * operator as in a ?formula-class object, but that operator does something different in ?lavaan::model.syntax.  The lavaan package does not directly support latent moderation models, but the semTools package enables product-indicator approaches (see ?indProd help page, and the functions listed under "see also"). See aalso the modsem package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=modsem
